# How to talk about contamination in wort, beer, and food in general, to make it clear it's about bacteria?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes unwanted microorganisms find a way to food, and start to ferment it. Common term for this is "infection", but some people argue it is invalid, because, well, food isn't alive. Other term for this is "contamination", but that does not differentiate bacteria issue and lead or iron issue.

Is there a valid, not uncommon, and easily recognizable word for bacteria, wild yeast, mold etc contamination? One that does not include heavy metal contamination or sanitizer contamination?

Comment: As you state, in the beer brewing industry (in North American anyway) it is properly and all but universally called an _“infection”_, or simply _“infected”_.  Beer yeast **_is_** alive while fermenting – which is when it becomes infected – not that that preclusion is particularly valid anyway, it seems to me.  If you don't think the general consumer will understand what that means in your given context, then you might educate them.  : )

Comment: *bacterial contamination*

Answer (score 3):

**Biological contamination**, not a single word, but the most common term.

> Food contamination can occur in many different ways. Four main causes of food contamination are:
>   1. Not washing hands
>   2. Cross-contamination
>   3. Improper storage and cooking temperatures
>   4. Contamination by animal waste
>
> Contaminants can be [commonly] divided into three categories:
>
> Physical: wood, metal, glass, paint chips, hair
>   Chemical: cleaning chemicals, maintenance chemicals, pest control chemicals
>   Biological: micro organisms, insects, rodents, birds
>
> Source: [Safe Food Handling](https://sites.google.com/site/safefoodhandling/food-contamination)

Biological contaminants — [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/biological-contaminants.html)

> Living organisms (such as bacteria, enzymes, fungi, viruses) or their products that can be hazardous to animal or human health if inhaled, swallowed, or otherwise absorbed into the body.

If a person/animal consumes "contaminated food", they may get "infected" by the microorganisms.

<sub>Related: Biological contamination — [TFD](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Biological+contamination)</sub>

> <sup>The contamination of a building environment caused by bacteria, molds and their spores, pollen, viruses, and other biological materials</sup>